# Groupby Barplot for top 10 values in a dataset - getting error 'Rectangle' object has no property 'hue' Python

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn

Super new to Python.

I want to plot a barplot or countplot of the top 10 restaurants (with highest order volume i.e. count) with a hue of day of the week i.e. weekday or weekend.

I am able to plot the first part using below code:

```
df.groupby(by=['restaurant_name'])['cost_of_the_order'].count().reset_index().sort_values(['cost_of_the_order'],
                    ascending=True).tail(10).plot(x='restaurant_name',kind='bar', figsize=(15,5))

plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
```

But whenever I add

```
hue = 'day_of_the_week'
```

to

```
 df.groupby(by=['restaurant_name'])['cost_of_the_order'].count().reset_index().sort_values(['cost_of_the_order'],
    ascending=True).tail(10).plot(x='restaurant_name',kind='bar', 
    hue = 'day_of_the_week', figsize=(15,5))
```

I get an error code which I will past below.

The output that I am looking for is a table similar to below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAwBn.png)

But has 2 bars for each restaurant, one bar being weekend and the other weekday OR a stacked version. Is there a way to do this efficiently? Is groupby the wrong approach?

Thanks in adavance.

Error code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18864/2327115462.py in <module>
----> 1 df.groupby(by=['restaurant_name'])['cost_of_the_order'].count().reset_index().sort_values(['cost_of_the_order'],
      2                     ascending=True).tail(10).plot(x='restaurant_name',kind='bar', hue = 'day_of_the_week', figsize=(15,5))
      3 
      4 plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    970                     data.columns = label_name
    971 
--> 972         return plot_backend.plot(data, kind=kind, **kwargs)
    973 
    974     __call__.__doc__ = __doc__

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\__init__.py in plot(data, kind, **kwargs)
     69             kwargs["ax"] = getattr(ax, "left_ax", ax)
     70     plot_obj = PLOT_CLASSES[kind](data, **kwargs)
---> 71     plot_obj.generate()
     72     plot_obj.draw()
     73     return plot_obj.result

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\core.py in generate(self)
    286         self._compute_plot_data()
    287         self._setup_subplots()
--> 288         self._make_plot()
    289         self._add_table()
    290         self._make_legend()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\core.py in _make_plot(self)
   1507             else:
   1508                 w = self.bar_width / K
-> 1509                 rect = self._plot(
   1510                     ax,
   1511                     self.ax_pos + (i + 0.5) * w,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\core.py in _plot(cls, ax, x, y, w, start, log, **kwds)
   1437     @classmethod
   1438     def _plot(cls, ax: Axes, x, y, w, start=0, log=False, **kwds):
-> 1439         return ax.bar(x, y, w, bottom=start, log=log, **kwds)
   1440 
   1441     @property

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1359     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1360         if data is None:
-> 1361             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1362 
   1363         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in bar(self, x, height, width, bottom, align, **kwargs)
   2363                 hatch=htch,
   2364                 )
-> 2365             r.update(kwargs)
   2366             r.get_path()._interpolation_steps = 100
   2367             if orientation == 'vertical':

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in update(self, props)
   1060                     func = getattr(self, f"set_{k}", None)
   1061                     if not callable(func):
-> 1062                         raise AttributeError(f"{type(self).__name__!r} object "
   1063                                              f"has no property {k!r}")
   1064                     ret.append(func(v))

AttributeError: 'Rectangle' object has no property 'hue'
```

Comment: You are using pandas plotting. Unlike seaborn, pandas does not have a hue parameter. For hue, you'll need `sns.barplot`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, will try it again using another method

Comment: Maybe something like `sns.countplot(data=df, x='restaurant', hue='day_of_the_week',
              order=df['restaurant'].value_counts().index[-10:])` ?

Comment: If I found a roundabout way to do it should I post as answer?
My issue was that restaurant name was being treated as a category, so when I changed it to an object the graphs looked more presentable. I used pivot table to plot the table   {pd.pivot_table(topdf, 'Revenue', index = 'restaurant_name', columns = 'day_of_the_week', aggfunc = np.sum
              ).plot(kind = 'bar', stacked=False, figsize=(15,5)).xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')}